# Where did my shadows and reflections go?

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

**The problem:**

-I started on making a background for my model and once I added planes the lighting and reflections have disappeared.

-I am new to Blender and this is my 3rd model I have made mainly following a tutorial,  using version 3.3.1 with Eevee as my render engine.

-I am using a laptop so my rendering and processing power is very slow

**Things I have tried:**

- making sure shadows are enabled and that the lighting is enabled for the render
- deleting the light and adding a new one
- using different types of lights and changing the power, radius, and max distance
- closing and opening Blender which sometimes will show shadows but then they suddenly disappear

How do I enable the lighting and reflections in my render?

Edit:

- I am not using any glossy textures and my renders aren't completely black
- my light source is behind my camera
- scene lights are turned on

Left: render preview, Right: material preview
[image: Left: render preview, Right: material preview]

[image]

Comment: Check if Scene Lights are checked under display properties ... Isn't light position inside the cat or behinds the wall ... If not probably better to share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ to let us inspect ...

Comment: So ... your Spot light  10W is too low for this distance. When set to 1000W  or Sun light to 3 it works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you @vklidu, I ended up needing to restart Blender along with my laptop. The light settings were adjusted and now I can see the shadows....thanks again!